# Is it okay to use つ counting for everything?

Tags: counters

Instead of using the proper counter for each thing, is it okay to just use the つ counter?

Like in:

> 彼女は子猫２匹を持っている。

Use つ instead of 匹:

> 彼女は子猫２つを持っている。

Are there situations when this is incorrect or not recommended?

Comment: Off topic: it's much more natural to use 2匹 adverbially, e.g. 子猫を２匹.

Comment: And "to have (a pet)" is (ペットを)飼【か】っている. 持っている is wrong unless you mean holding two cats in one's arms.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

つ is a generic *inanimate* counter.  It might be confusing sometimes, but you can get away with using it for lots of inanimate objects if you don't know a more appropriate counter.

**Don't use つ for animals or people.**

You should use 匹 for kittens in your example, not つ. The basic counter for people is 人{にん}.

In general, animate objects (animals and people) have special counters.  No matter how long and thin a snake may be, you can't use the inanimate counter for long and slender objects (本) to refer to it.  And you should never refer to people like they're inanimate objects.

If you don't already know them, you should try to learn some basic counters at some point.  Planning on using つ *all* the time is no good.  Some of the most common ones include
人・名・匹 (animates) and 本・枚・台 (inanimates), along with つ and 個.

Comment: It is said that つ counting is only up to 10. This limit denotes the max for つ counting or just the hito-futa-mi numbers? 個 also has this limit?

Comment: @BrunoLopes It's because つ is no longer "productive", which means it doesn't combine with new things anymore.  All the combinations of つ with numerals are pre-formed in the Japanese vocabulary, and there are only nine of them (plus とお, where つ is technically absent).  個 is still productive and can attach to larger numbers (from the other system, of course).

Comment: So "25 books" could be 本25（にじゅうご）個　?

Comment: For 本(book), use [冊]{さつ}... eg 彼女は本を[25冊]{にじゅうごさつ}持っています。

Comment: @choco But in case 個 is used, as a general object counter, would the sentence be correct? Or it can't be used for books?

Comment: I wrote an article about the generic counter. http://lang-8.com/1258954/journals/271307152612572000329247151022127481902

Comment: @BrunoLopes You don't use 個 or つ for books...

Comment: @choco つ is no problem.

Comment: えっ！？「本を三つ読んだ。」とか「本を三つ借りました。」なんて言います？私は言いませんが。

Comment: ３つ読んだは確かに使わないと思いますが、３つ借りたは特に変だと思わないです。

Comment: More precisely,  1読む 2積む(pile up) 3借りる・買う 4たのむ(order), in this order, 冊's dominance feels solid, for some reason.

Comment: I searched and found out why it's not used for books: because 個 is used only for small objects, instead of all, as is erroneously said in some sites.

Comment: @BrunoLopes Downing defines 個 as the counter for 'small objects of roughly equal extension in all three dimensions', but I think some children use 個 as a generic counter.

Comment: Even adults sometimes slip 個. As for the difference between つ, "eye" takes つ while "eye-ball" takes 個.

Comment: I doubt that 個 should be defined as the counter for small objects, because Ayers Rock is 一個.

Answer (score 2):

It might work for most objects.

For some other concepts it won't be understandable at all, though, for instance don't use it for:

- Hours/days/months/etc
- People (as snailboat said)
- Number of occurences
- Distances