# つ at the end of a number

Tags: counters, numbers

I just recently started to learn Japanese and I am a bit confused with some numbers. For example, what is the difference between 七 (なな) and 七つ (ななつ). Is there no difference? Is it just another way of saying it?

Comment: Apparently you haven't been told about counter words: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_counter_word

Comment: @Earthliŋ 
"Used as part of the indigenous Japanese numbers" Does this mean that it is always used when counting.

Comment: When counting objects/days/whatever, yes. Determining the correct counter can be difficult, but つ is a generic counter that may be used to count many inanimate objects, which is why it's usually the first counter for objects people learn. Also see http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/28026/1628.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

つ is a [counter word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_counter_word) (for generic inanimate objects), so that

> 七 (なな) "[the number] seven"
>   七つ (ななつ) "seven [objects]"

Similarly you have

> 七日 (なのか) "the seventh [day of the month]"
>   七本 (ななほん) "seven [longish objects]"

and many many more.

Depending on the counter, the numbers may not be based on the native Japanese numbers (*hito*, *futa*, *mi*, ..., ***nana***, ...), but on the Sino-Japanese numbers (*ichi*, *ni*, *san*, ..., ***shichi***, ...), as in

> 七時間 (しちじかん) "seven hours"

When the numbers (like 七) *count* something, you use a counter word. When you talk about the number as a number (e.g. in telephone numbers), you use the number without the counter word.